# Query execute in database but not when execute in WebService

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, asmx

I've got some problem in my WebService. When I execute my query in my database, return fine, but when I execute through the service (online), returns the error 
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '&lt;'.`

**CODE**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument listagemCredenciadasCoordenadaGeografica(string latitude, string longitude, float raio)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "SELECT San_Filial.Credenciada_Id " 
                + "FROM San_Filial " 
                + "WHERE (San_Filial.Excluido = 0) " 
                + "AND (San_Filial.Credenciada_Id NOT IN (62, 85, 1, 68, 10, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155)) " 
                + "AND San_Filial.lat != '0' " 
                + "AND San_Filial.lat IS NOT NULL "
                + "AND San_Filial.ddd IS NOT NULL " 
                + "AND ACOS( COS(RADIANS(RTRIM(LTRIM(San_Filial.lat)))) * " 
                + "COS(RADIANS(convert(float," + latitude + "))) * " 
                + "COS(RADIANS(RTRIM(LTRIM(San_Filial.lon))) - " 
                + "RADIANS(convert(float," + longitude + "))) + " 
                + "SIN(RADIANS(RTRIM(LTRIM(San_Filial.lat))) * " 
                + "SIN(RADIANS(convert(float," + latitude + ")))) * 6380 < " + raio + " ";

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(ExecuteStrQuery(s, "Table").GetXml());

            return xml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


public static DataSet ExecuteStrQuery(string Query, string NameTable)
        {
            neticonn.ConexaoWebServices conn = new neticonn.ConexaoWebServices();
            SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conn.novaConexao("netservicemobile"));

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, c);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds, NameTable);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if (c.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        c.Close();
                        c.Dispose();
                        da.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: `c.Dispose();` and `da.Dispose();` are not needed.

Comment: Also, never use `throw ex;`. Use `throw;` to rethrow an exception, or better still, don't catch it in the first place.

Comment: @Brian: why aren't they needed? He's not using `using` blocks.

Comment: What is the Query argument being sent to your method?

Comment: Keep a break point after s and copy its value and paste in SSMS.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - GC will do it for him and it's just extra verbosity.

Comment: 1. Copy the generated string S and run in the DB. 2. To make sure < is not creating problem, replace it with = and then try to run the query

Comment: @Brian: wish I could downvote your comment. GC will do it for him _eventually_, when it gets around to it. In the meantime, he's holding on to resources he's not using.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - You can flag it if you find it so offensive...

Comment: @Brian: not offensive, just wrong and very bad advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts come to mind.

1) Whenever doing a sql query, please use parameterized queries... named parameters is even better.  Concatenation is bad, bad, bad!  If you're unfamiliar, read up on SQL Injection.

2) `&lt;` is html for `<`, so my guess is you need to look into html encode/decode before you use the value for querying